# zsh alias for running the most recent matching history item

Tags: command-line, terminal, unix, shell, zsh

I'd like to create an alias in zsh that runs my last terminal command beginning with `node`. I can run that command with `!?node`, but I can't create an alias with `alias N='!?node'`. How can I make this alias?

Comment: You are missing the closing `'`?

Comment: Good catch! I still have the problem, though.

Comment: Another way to phrase this question: is it possible to add a custom history expansion to zsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

History expansion is performed on your command line [*before* alias expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Expansion). So, putting a history expansion into an alias won’t work, because, after the alias gets expanded, no more history expansion is performed.

Parameter expansion, on the other hand, is performed *after* alias expansion. So, you can use this instead:

```bash
alias N='"${(z)history[(r)node *]}"'
```

- [`(r)` gets the first occurrence of the pattern after it](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts). In this case, it will retrieve the most recent matching history item, because [`$history` is always ordered from newest to oldest](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module).
- [`(z)` parses the string as code and returns the resulting shell words](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags). Otherwise, the entire expansion is treated as a single word.
- The `"`double quotes`"` are necessary to get the space parsed correctly. Otherwise, it would be treated as a word separator, resulting in a syntax error.
- The `'`single quotes`'` are necessary to prevent the parameter expansion from being peformed immediately on declaration.

Comment: Thank you, Marlon! This solution nearly worked for me. I used `alias N='$=history[(r)node?*]'` (using a question mark instead of a space). This runs the last command beginning with 'node ' (note the space).

Comment: Ah, sorry. I hadn’t tested it and just wrote it off the top of my head. I’ve updated my answer. Have a look; it’s more precise than your solution.